# Display data from Mysql table with style

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have written a code that can save data from mysql using PHP, so how can I display it using table styled with CSS. The datum stored in my server are: Name of the product, the specs of the product, its price and the link of the image of the product. How can I display all of those with this kind of format:

[image: Table Format]

And this is its source code:

```
  <body>

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
<center><font color="White" size="+12"><u>PROCESSORS</u></font></center>
<table border=0 align="center">
<th colspan="3"><h2><font color="White">AMD PROCESSORS</font></h2></th>
<th></th>
<th colspan="3"><h2><font color="White">INTEL PROCESSORS</font></h2></th>
<tr><td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
 <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900"> AMD ATHLON II X2 260</th>
<tr><td >Specs:</td><td>3.20Ghz<br />2 cores<br />2Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and x64 
OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td >Price:</td><td>2500</td></tr>
<tr><td >Quantity:</td><td><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td >Add to cart?</td><td ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="AMD">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="AMD ATHLON II X2 260">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="2500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd1.jpg" />
</td>

<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">INTEL i3</th>
<tr><td >Specs:</td><td >3.20Ghz<br />2 cores<br />3Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and x64 
OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td >Price:</td><td >2500</td></tr>
<tr><td >Quantity:</td><td  ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td >Add to cart?</td><td  ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="INTEL">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="INTEL i3">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="2500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd5.jpg" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">AMD SEMPRON</th>
<tr><td >Specs:</td><td >2.20Ghz<br />4 cores<br />4Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and x64 
OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Price:</td><td  >3000</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Quantity:</td><td   ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td  >Add to cart?</td><td   ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="AMD">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="AMD SEMPRON">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="3000">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd2.jpg" />
</td>

<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">INTEL i5</th>
<tr><td  >Specs:</td><td  >3.40Ghz<br />4 cores<br />6Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and 
x64 OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Price:</td><td  >5500</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Quantity:</td><td   ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td  >Add to cart?</td><td   ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="INTEL">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="INTEL i5">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="5500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd6.jpg" />
</td>

</tr>
<tr><td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">AMD PHENOM II x6</th>
<tr><td  >Specs:</td><td  >3.7 GHz<br />6 cores<br />6Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and 
x64 OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Price:</td><td  >4500</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Quantity:</td><td   ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td  >Add to cart?</td><td   ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="AMD">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="AMD PHENOM II x6">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="4500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd3.jpg" />
</td>

<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">INTEL i7</th>
<tr><td  >Specs:</td><td  >4.0Ghz<br />4 cores<br />8Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and x64
OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Price:</td><td  >6500</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Quantity:</td><td   ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td  >Add to cart?</td><td   ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="INTEL">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="INTEL i7">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="6500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd7.jpg" />
</td>

</tr>
<tr><td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">AMD OPTERON x16</th>
  <tr><td  >Specs:</td><td  >3.30Ghz<br />16 cores<br />2Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and
 x64 OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
  <tr><td  >Price:</td><td  >7500</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Quantity:</td><td   ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
 <tr><td  >Add to cart?</td><td   ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="AMD">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="AMD OPTERON x16">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="7500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd4.jpg" />
</td>

<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<form action=cds.php method=get>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
  <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FF9900">INTEL PENTIUM 4 G870</th>
<tr><td  >Specs:</td><td  >3.20Ghz<br />2 cores<br />2Mb Cache<br />Supports x86 and 
x64 OS<br />w/ Cool'n Quiet Tech</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Price:</td><td  >3500</td></tr>
<tr><td  >Quantity:</td><td   ><input type=text name=quant></td></tr>
<tr><td  >Add to cart?</td><td   ><input type="submit" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type=hidden name=comp value="INTEL">
<input type=hidden name=prdname value="INTEL PENTIUM G870">
<input type=hidden name=prc value="3500">
</form>
</td>
<br />
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<img src="img/prd8.jpg" />
    </td>

</tr>
<tr><td><br /><br /></td></tr>
</table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I know it will need loops to print all the rows in the mysql table but it has multiple cells, do I have to use nested loops to print that?

Comment: first complete the design and at the start of the page get data from database and where you want to display data from database use inline script like <?php echo 'product name' ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    //get data from database related to that product 
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSCO))
   {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>;
    echo '<td>';
    echo 'Prodcut name';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr> </table>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: what you want to use ? i didn't get u

Comment: I edited my comment sorry, this is the code that i want to use    

[click me](http://pastebin.com/K9eBhQiG)

Comment: so you got the idea of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

What you present is a loop so use a loop (even multiple). Insert all this values to db rows adding the necessary columns and use WHILE LOOP to fetch the data. Enclose just one table html inside the loop, so you don't repeat the code.

> The faster way is to create a function with the product name
>   fetching the data from the db.  That will save you a lot of time
>
> Correct the forms, closing the quotation on the input field

```
<input type=hidden name="comp" value="">
    <input type=hidden name="prdname" value="">
    <input type=hidden name="prc" value="">

and <form action="cds.php" method="get">
(for this need, I would prefer method POST)
```